# Displaying Time Zone on Event pages

Tags: civievent, timezone

I am using Civi 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.4
Currently CiviEvent pages display the date and the time in the format you see in the screen shot.  How are people supposed to know what time zone that is in? My clients need to show the time zone of each event they schedule.  How can I do this?

[image]
Thank you

Comment: could you add a custom field to 'event' and then show the timezone in that?

Comment: I am open to doing that.  Will it display the timezone right next to the time?

Comment: not without some theming